# Parent Container Collapsing In Responsive jQuery Slider

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I have a jQuery Slider that I am trying to make responsive, here is a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mwcw4swf/1/

The problem I'm having is that I have to set the height of the parent container or else it collapses:

```css
#sliderWrapper {
    max-width: 800px;
    height: 200px; 
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

I tried using a clearfix to stop it from happening but it doesn't seem to work: http://jsfiddle.net/mwcw4swf/2/

```
<div  class="spacer"></div>
```

CSS:

```css
.spacer {
    height: 0;
    clear:both;
}
```

Are there any other  ways of stopping a  parent container from collapsing while still keeping the slider responsive ?

---

What I mean by responsive is that I want the entire slider to resize depending on the browser size. To do this I need to not use a set height on the size of the container, but when I take the height off the whole slider collapses as shown in the second fiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why you have removed the `#sliderList` element from normal flow by using absolute positioning.

This is because the `#sliderWrapper` won't take the height of its contents. You could avoid absolute positioning to fix the issue:

**[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/mwcw4swf/4/)**

```css
#sliderList {
    list-style: none;
    /* left: 0px; position: absolute; */
    position: relative;
    width: 200000em;
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
}
```

Then safely remove the specified `height` from the wrapper.

---

### Fixing the gap under images

Also there's a ~5px gap under the images (inline level elements) which belongs to the lowercase letters having descenders in inline flow. You could fix that by positioning images by `vertical-align` property:

```css
#sliderWrapper img { vertical-align: middle; }
```

---

### Make it responsive!

In order to make the slider responsive, you have to set the `width` of slider items with the respect to the width of viewport. This could happen either by using **[viewport units](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths)** `100vw` or the following JavaScript code:

**[Example Here](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/mwcw4swf/6/)**

```css
$(window).resize(function () {
    $('.sliderItem').width($(window).width());
}).resize(); /* trigger the handler */
```

*PS: I've also refined the markup and some of declarations in the demo*

Comment: The `#sliderList` should actually positioned **relative** to make the animation work.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, if I resize the browser the images still stay the same height and flow off the page. Also that stops the images from sliding, now they just change rather than slide in.

Comment: Here is an  example of what I mean by responsive https://www.caesarscasino.com/ When you resize the browser the banner also resizes so that you can still see the full image

Comment: @Mikey *This* was an answer to `Are there any other ways of stopping a parent container from collapsing` question. However I'm working on it to make it responsive, I'll update the answer in few minutes.

Comment: That's perfect ! Thanks so much, was really struggling to figure this out